# Laravel + Livewire: will CRUD in livewire component cause future problems

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to learn Laravel and Livewire. Will it cause future problems if the CRUD is placed in a Livewire Component instead of a Controller?

Code inside the livewire component:

```php
    public function create()
    {
        $this->validate();
        Page::create($this->modelData());
        $this->modalFormVisible = false;
        $this->reset();
    }

    public function read()
    {
        return Page::paginate(5);
    }


    public function update()
    {
        $this->validate();
        Page::find($this->modelId)->update($this->modelData());
        $this->modalFormVisible = false;
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        Page::destroy($this->modelId);
        $this->modalConfirmDeleteVisible = false;
        $this->resetPage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with implementing the crud functionality within a livewire component as long as that is that livewire component's main purpose. A livewire component is just another alternative solution equal to a controller.